# Why is $\tilde{H}_0(X)\cong H_0(X,x_0)$?

Tags: algebraic-topology

$x_0$ is a point in $X$.

I can see (from the long exact sequence of the pair $(X,x_0)$) that $$\tilde{H}_0(X)\cong \tilde{H}_0(X,x_0).$$

But how can we justify removing the tilde from $H_0$?

By definition,
$$\tilde{H}_0(X,x_0)=\ker(H_0(X,x_0)\to H_0(*))$$

but how is that equal to $H_0(X,x_0)?$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$H_0(X,x_0)$ is the $0$-homology of the chain complex
$$
\frac{C_1(X)}{C_1(x_0)} \to \frac{C_0(X)}{C_0(x_0)} \to 0
$$
Compare: $\tilde{H}(X,x_0)$ is the $0$-homology of the "extended" chain complex
$$
\frac{C_1(X)}{C_1(x_0)} \to \frac{C_0(X)}{C_0(x_0)} \to \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{\mathbb{Z}}\simeq 0.
$$

Comment: Oh ok, I was thinking that by extending it I would get $$
\frac{C_1(X)}{C_1(x_0)} \to \frac{C_0(X)}{C_0(x_0)} \to \mathbb{Z} \to 0
$$, which didn't look the same as the $H_0(X,x_0)$ case (because, in fact, it isn't). Thanks!